# How to preserve themes/plugins when autoscaling Wordpress instances

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Forgive me if this is an obvious question, but I am trying to figure out what the best way is of handling autoscaling of EC2 instances running WordPress such that their **themes** and **plugins** (along with their associated configurations) are preserved.

I am already able to decouple the data and content layers via RDS and S3, respectively, but I am struggling how to preserve the themes and plugins through an EC2 instance autoscaling event.

My EC2 instances are configured as follows:

- EC2 bootstrap script installs WordPress onto blank Amazon Linux AMI
- EC2 runs behind an ELB
- Database is on RDS
- Web content is on S3 (using W3 Total Cache plugin)
- Plugins/themes are installed on the local EC2 filesystem

To preserve themes and/or plugins through an EC2 autoscaling event, I could:

1. Install the themes/plugins I need first, then upload the /wp-content/plugins and /wp-content/themes dirs to **S3**, downloading them automatically each time an EC2 instance restarts via the bootstrap script. DISADVANTAGES: need to update S3 every time i make a config change, not all plugins are installed neatly within the /themes subdir, and changes to one instance don't flow to all (need to restart the cluster everytime a change is made).
2. Install the themes/plugins I need first, then take an **AMI** snapshot of the entire instance. Use this AMI as a template when launching new instances. DISADVANTAGES: need to update the AMI every time i make a config change (seems tiresome), and changes to one instance don't flow to all.
3. Create a symbolic link out of the /wp-content/plugins and /wp-content/themes dirs, pointing to an **EFS** filesystem that is mounted on all EC2 instances. DISADVANTAGES: EFS can be a bit slow, not all plugins are installed entirely within the /themes subdir.

Anybody have any experience with this? Am I over-engineering this? Perhaps the themes/plugin files don't really change much throughout the lifespan of your WordPress blog (ie, once you're set up, you don't really find yourself changing them much), in which case maybe Option 1 (zip to S3 and download via bootstrap script) is the best option for me, and Option 3 (EFS) is over-engineered.

I would love to get your take on this if you have experience with this conundrum!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at this link:

https://cloudonaut.io/wordpress-on-aws-smooth-and-pain-free/

It provides a CloudFormation template that sets up an ASG backed by EFS, installs wordpress and some plugins there, uses RDS for their database, sets up CloudFront as CDN and a few other goodies.

I tweaked their template for our use case and added an extra ASG with spot instances, replaced all the VPC stuff with references to my VPC template and tweaked the LaunchConfig so it automatically sets up the S3 Offload plugin with a bucket created on my template. It also automatically sets up the certificate for the ELB and a few other goodies.

I thought that would be the end and that I would be able to forget about WordPress and leave another team to work on it. Wrong. They complained it felt sluggish and some plugins failed to install with timeouts (and installing them manually using wp-cli took way too long, one of them up to 2 minutes and a half).

So here my 2 cents: set up RDS and CloudFront, use a reserved instance for wordpress and offload your static assets to S3 using a plugin. Once the site is completely set up bake an AMI or take a snapshot of your EBS and set alarms so in case the instance breaks down you can quickly spin up a new one with your AMI/snapshot.

Either that or have your dev team baking AMIs from a dev environment so you can set up an ASG in your production environment with those.

I got to a point where I believe trying to set up WordPress for a non-dev team (meaning, they can install/upload plugins and themes from the browser) in an ASG is just madness without support from a dev team (baking AMIs, updating stacks). You could, of course, automate all of this. You could, of course, develop a full new site using anything else. Your call.

/rant